# Can I use my late 2013 MBP with Dell2515H?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, macos

I'm thinking to get an external monitor for my MacBook Pro Retina display (late 2013 model).

What I would like to have is to get a 4K monitor or QHD monitor (Dell U2515H or P2715Q).

What I'm worried about is the font and icons size on the external monitor. Should I expect them to be tiny and hard to read text?

My graphic card is Intel Iris 1536 MB.

Comment: The answer depends on whether you have a 13 inch or 15 inch model. I'm guessing 13 inch by the Iris graphics card.

Comment: @Andrew yes, I have 13 inches model. It could be used with u2515h ?

Comment: I'm trying to work this out myself! What I do know is that this model supports 4k for some monitors, but only at 30hz. This might be a deal breaker for you?

Comment: @Andrew I'm not going to play games. I only wants bigger monitor for coding, surfing , etc ...

Comment: The answer to my related question may help you : http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/204810/what-is-the-maximum-supported-resolution-of-the-macbook-pro-retina-13-inch-la

Answer (score 1):

You can use 4K displays and Ultra HD TVs with these Mac computers:

- MacBook Pro (Retina, Late 2013 and later)
- Mac Pro (Late 2013)
- iMac (27-inch, Late 2013 and later)
- Mac mini (Late 2014)
- MacBook Air (Early 2015)
- MacBook (Retina, 12-inch, Early 2015)

So yes, your MacBook will support a 4K external monitor. You can decide how big you would like your interface/text etc. to appear in system preferences the same way you can on your internal monitor.

Source: [Apple Support Documents](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202856)

Comment: What are available scaled resolution, do you know?

Comment: The list above does not specify 13 inch or 15 inch MacBooks. If 13 inch (as I believe the specification of the question points to) then this answer is quite possibly not correct.

Comment: @KevinGrabher Can you cite any sources or documentation on this? At least for the first one, MacBook Pro Retina Late 2013, 4K exceeds [Apple's specs page](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP690?locale=en_US) though I've heard the underlying hardware may be capable. I would like to be certain before bothering to research and purchase a 4K monitor.

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202856

Comment: Actually @Andrew is correct. 13 inches late 2013 is not supporting high resolutions. I got today U2515H and it is not working . Constant flickering each one or two seconds

Comment: What connection did you use? Did you fiddle with the settings. According to the Apple Support Document 4K should be supported (at least at 30Hz)