# What is the maximum supported resolution of the MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Late 2013) for an external monitor at 60hz

Tags: macbook-pro, display, resolution

I have a MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Late 2013). It has 8GB Ram and Intel Iris 1536 MB .

I want to buy a good external monitor, but I can't find a straight answer as to what this model supports with either Thunderbolt or HDMI.

What is the maximum supported resolution of this model for an external monitor at 60hz ?

(Please note that I don't care about any answers for the 15-inch model or 2015 versions. I only care specifically for the Late 2013 13 inch)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to Apple's [MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Late 2013) - Technical Specifications](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP691?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)...

[image]

So it looks like 1080p is the 60Hz limit.

Comment: 1080p would be a resolution of 1920 x 1080, which would match my existing external monitor, so great to know.

Comment: That last line should add the qualifier "on HDMI". I believe DisplayPort through the Thunderbolt port will give better support for higher-than-HD resolutions.

Comment: @BasilBourque, Since it's directly under **HDMI video output**, in bold no less, and it is external which it was the OP was asking about, I don't feel it needs additional qualification.

Answer (score 7):

I know I am late to this question, but I own the "MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Late 2013)" with "Intel Iris 1536 MB". I am currently using the macbook with the "Samsung SMS27A850" according to the system preferences it is currently running at 2560 x 1440 @ 60 Hz using the DisplayPort/Thunderbolt connection (not HDMI).

Comment: @Tetsujin thanks negative troll. except that my answer contradicts the accepted answer, because it only specifies HDMI.

Comment: @vossman77 - thanks for adding this answer, it was a help to me.