# 2560x1440 @ 60 Hz HiDpi on a MBPr 13" Late 2013

Tags: display, displayport, resolution

My setup:

- Late 2013 13" MacBook Pro Retina (MBPr)
- Dell P2715Q (4k) monitor
- Connect the MBPr with the monitor using a mDP-DP cable

SwitchResX shows me the following resolutions:

[image]

- I tried the 2560x1440 @ 30 Hz HiDpi resolution, but there is so much lag that I would really like 60 Hz.
- I tried the 2560x1440 @ 60 Hz (no HiDpi) resolution, but this does not look very clear on this monitor.

I read [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/239594/160302) that my model MacBook should support 2560x1440 @ 60 Hz, but I suppose this is without HiDpi? Is there a way for me to get a 2560x1440 @ 60 Hz HiDpi resolution, or does my MacBook simply not support this?

Comment: When selecting 2560x1440 (both HiDpi and not), does the display details see a 1440p signal or a 2160p signal?